# remove specified data from list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list like:

```
datalist = list(X1 = c(150, 146, 146, 142, 141), X2 = c(146, 146, 
142, 141, 150), X3 = c(146, 142, 141, 150, 158), X4 = c(142, 
141, 150, 158, 155))
```

How can I remove 158 from the lists datalist?

thanks

Comment: Why 158? It is not in $X2.

Comment: yes, I just want to delete 158, not in all element

Comment: I guess you want `lapply(datalist, function(x) x[x != 158])`. This is surely a duplicate but not the one @Barbara linked to

Comment: I have edit my post

Comment: @RonakShah, your dupe link looks good except that the accepted answer loops over the indices whereas they could just loop over the list directly

Comment: @docendodiscimus which has been explained in your comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find the numbers that are common in all list elements, you could use

```
common <- Reduce(intersect, datalist, datalist[[1]])
```

In order to remove an element, you could use, as @docendo discimus pointed out,

```
cleaned <- lapply(datalist, function(x) x[x != 158])
```